# Dynamically add views on click of Button using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-compose-button

I want to dynamically add Text Fields to my layout everytime user click "Add" button.Added Text Field should be added above "Add" button .i.e.between Step 1 TextField and Add Button.How can this be achieved through Jetpack Compose?Below is screenshot followed by my current code..

[image]

Code-

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {

            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                value = step1,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onStep1Changed(it)
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Step 1...")
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start=10.dp),
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Image,
                        tint= Color.Blue,
                        contentDescription = "Select Image"
                    )
                }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
             //TODO Dynamically add text fields
            }){
                Text("Add")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
val textFieldCount by remember { mutableStateOf (1) }
            repeat(textFieldCount) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                value = step1,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onStep1Changed(it)
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Step 1...")
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start=10.dp),
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Image,
                        tint= Color.Blue,
                        contentDescription = "Select Image"
                    )
                }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        }
            Button(onClick = {
             textFieldCount++
            }){
                Text("Add")
            }

        }
```

Comment: if we type in one textfield , value of all text fields will be changed.
How to fix that.

Comment: I have a similar case, but with Row. I add Text() into Row by going through an array. Every time the array changes I need to remove added Text() and start adding again. How Do I achieve that? Is there any removeAllViews() for Row? Thanks

Comment: @MarkDelphi If you just need to display stuff from an array, change the array to a mutable state list object. `val list = mutableStateListOf<T>()`, where `T` is the data type. Then, simple do a `forEach` loopover and have the Texts rendered.

Comment: @KaranAhuja define the value inside the loop, it won't change that way. Better still, create a mutable state list as described in the comment above to hold the values for the text, store it in a viewmodel, and use state-hoisting to read it from your text composables.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper thanks.
currently using xml views . need to figure out how to store state in viewmodel and use it in a composable...
will look into the docs for next project.